# Universal graph

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, geometric-group-theory, coarse-geometry

A connected (and infinite) graph $U$ will be called *$n$-universal* if any connected graph with degree $\leqslant n$ admits an embedding in $U$.

> Is there a 3-universal graph with bounded degree?

Comment: Is there some assumption of connectedness on the sources or target?

Comment: @SamNead yes, it is fixed now.

Comment: @NoahSchweber you are very fast, now I do not see a way to fix it.

Comment: If I write enough things fast enough, one of them will eventually be true.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti Nope - every connected bounded-degree graph is countable (I made exactly this mistake, multiple times, earlier).

Comment: Ah, that's interesting, is there an easy argument to see that must be the case? @NoahSchweber

Comment: Not Noah, but if you fix a starting vertex $v$ and, at step $i$, collect all neighbors of the vertices you have so far, then you will exhaust the graph in countably-many steps with only finitely many vertexes added at each step. EDIT: If I'm not mistaken, the same argument establishes countability if you only assume that each vertex has finite degree.

Comment: Dangit, I had stuff to do today ...

Comment: Which notion of subgraph / embedding are you considering? Induced or not? Equivalently, should every edge between vertices in the image « come from » an edge in the embedded subgraph?

Comment: @CorentinB NOT induced.

Comment: If $G,H$ are graphs such that $G$ contains an embedded copy of every finite subgraph of $H$, does this imply that $G$ contains an embedded copy of $H$? This sounds like a compactness theorem-type of statement. If that's true, we only need to arrange for $G$ to contain all finite $H$, which is easy to do.

Comment: @BenJohnsrude: that's obviously not true without some further assumptions on $G$ and $H$. For example, let $G$ be the disjoint union of countably many copies of all finite paths, and let $H$ be the infinite path.

Comment: @BenJohnsrude Nope: let $G$ be the successor graph on the naturals and $H$ the successor graph on the integers.

Comment: @Ben if we consider graphs with marked vertices and assume that embedding maps marked vertex to the marked vertex, then "yes". In this case it is enuf to do finite graphs.

Comment: Why can't you take all finite graphs with degrees $\leq 3$ and put them in a long chain with maximum degree 4?

Comment: @CommandMaster we aren't assuming that the graphs are finite, so there are uncountable many graphs we need to embed in $U$.

Comment: Do you know how to do this with all degrees $< \infty$ (that is, a locally finite graph)?

Comment: @CommandMaster This was done by Noah Schweber in his deleted answer. (It was a modification of the Rado-graph construction.)

Comment: I try to understand the deleted anser by Noah and do not succeed. How to make Rado construction locally finite? For me it seems crucial to add new and new edges from the same vertex.

Comment: @FedorPetrov he constructs a sequence of graphs $G_0\subset G_1\subset\dots$ Each vertex in $G_{n+1}\setminus G_n$ corresponds to a three-vertex subset in $G_n\setminus G_{n-1}$ and connected to its three-vertex subset.

Comment: I am happy even if $G_{n+1}\setminus G_n$ is connected to the whole $G_{n}\setminus G_{n-1}$, since we do not need induced embeddings and the degrees are still finite. But how to embed an arbitrary graph of degree 3 here?

Comment: @FedorPetrov One can embed $n$-balls inductively into $G_n$.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Noach, could you restore your construction of locally finite universal graph?

Comment: Ah, I see, the spheres sizes are bounded by an a priori sequence and the edges are only between neighbour spheres or inside the same sphere.

Comment: @CommandMaster The answer to your question about a locally finite universal graph is Corollary 3.2 in my paper "A note on classes of subgraphs of locally finite graphs" linked below Fedor Petrov's answer. There even is a locally finite graph which contains all graphs of maximum degree $d$ as induced subgraphs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think that the answer is negative.

Assume that such graph $G$ on the vertex set $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots\}$ exists. We construct our not-embeddable graph $H$ on $\{1,2,\ldots\}$ by steps. On the $i$-th step only finitely many edges are added to $H$, it is connected and has degrees at most 3, and there is no embedding of this finite graph $H_i$ to $G$ for which $1$ goes to $i$. I explain how to do the first step, all other are essentially the same.

We take a long path $P=1-2-\ldots -(6N)$ and partition the $2N$ vertices $2,5,\ldots,6N-1$ by pairs arbitrarily. We get $(2N-1)!!$ different labelled graphs. How much of them are embeddable to $G$ so that 1 goes to $v_1$? We should start with a path of length $6N-1$ from $v_1$ (exponentially many possibilities), which should be the image of $P$, then $G$ induced to $P$ has linearly many edges, and thus exponentially many subsets of these edges. So, only exponentially many such graphs are embeddable to $G$, and we may perform the first step.

Comment: Well, that explains why I was having trouble proving a positive answer!

Comment: To add a reference and some shameless self-promotion to this answer: this is Theorem 1.2 in my paper "A note on classes of subgraphs of locally finite graphs"

Comment: @FlorianLehner only irrelevant self-promotion is shameful :) By the way, is your argument similar to this?

Comment: Link to paper by Florian Lehner: [A note on classes of subgraphs of locally finite graphs](https://www.florian-lehner.net/pdf/universal-locally-finite.pdf) ([DOI](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jctb.2023.02.001)), *J. Combin. Theory Ser. B* 161 (2023), 52–62.

Comment: @FedorPetrov it is fairly similar; essentially it also uses the fact that there are too many finite rooted graphs with maximum degree 3 to embed them with the root at some fixed vertex